# Foreach em Datatable

Tags: c#, datatable

Tenha um `datatable` e precisava fazer um `foreach` para alterar alguns valores desse `datatable`

```
public static DataTable TabelaAmbientes { get; set; }
```

Estava fazendo o seguinte foreach:

```
foreach (DataRow lista in TabelaAmbientes.Rows)
                    {
                        switch (lista.CatRem_Tipo)
                        {
                            case "C":
                                lista.CatRem_Tipo = "Comissão/Participação";
                                break;

                            case "P":
                                lista.CatRem_Tipo = "Premiação";
                                break;

                            case "A":
                                lista.CatRem_Tipo = "Ambos";
                                break;
                         }
                      }
```

Mas ao fazer `lista.CatRem_Tipo` me da erro de

> DataRow não contém uma definição para CatRem_Tipo

O que posso fazer?

Comment: `lista["CatRem_Tipo"].Value` ???

Comment: Onde eu poderia colocar isso? no switch não da certo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assumindo que `CatRem_Tipo` é o nome da coluna:

```
var dic = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    { "C", "Comissão/Participação" },
    { "P", "Premiação" },
    { "A", "Ambos" }
};

foreach (DataRow dataRow in TabelaAmbientes.Rows)
{
    string value = dataRow["CatRem_Tipo"].ToString();

    if (dic.ContainsKey(value))
    {
       dataRow["CatRem_Tipo"] = dic[value];
    }
}
```

Edit: substituindo o `for` por `foreach`

Comment: Irei demorar um pouco a aceitar a resposta, pois não estou mais na empresa, mas amanhã cedo testo e já aceito, caso solucione meu problema

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta

Comment: Funcionou, obrigado